# Symmetric group of a hexagon as permutations

Tags: proof-verification, symmetric-groups

Write elements as permutations in $S_6$ of the dihedral group of symmetries of a regular hexagon inscribed in a unit circle with one vertex on the $x$-axis.

For the first part:

Let the hexagon be denoted the name $ABCDEF$, where $A$ is on the x-axis, $B$ above it and so on. I assign $1$ to $A$, $2$ to $B$ and in this way $6$ to $F$. The identity permutation is $e$, which is $R_0$. Then $R_{60}=(123456)$,$R_{120}=(135)(246)$, $R_{180}=(14)(25)(36)$, $R_{240}=(153)(264)$, $R_{300}=(165432)$, where $R_{\theta}$ denotes the rotation in the anti-clockwise direction by $\theta$.

For the reflections, there are six symmetries.

$V=(23)(14)(65)$, where $V$ is the vertical symmetry.

$H=(35)(26)$, where $H$ is the horizontal symmetry.

$D_1=(13)(46)$ , where $D_1$ is the line joining vertices $2$ and $5$

$D_2=(24)(15)$ , where $D_2$ is the line joining vertices $3$ and $6$

$D_3=(12)(36)(45)$ , where $D_3$ is the line passing through the midpoints of line joining vertices $1$,$2$ and$4$, $5$ .

$D_4=(16)(34)(25)$ , where $D_4$ is the line passing through the midpoints of line joining vertices $1$,$6$ and$4$, $3$.
Is this alright??

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: I think $D_1$ is wrong, but the others look OK. I don't care for the title; it's the dihedral group, not $S_6$, that you want to write as permutations.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks. $D_1=(13)(46)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symmetries of a regular hexagon are those of dihedral group 6, $D_6$.

Let $R_n$ denote a rotation around the centre of an angle $n \pi/ {\bf 3}$, for $n\in \{0,2,3,4,5\}$.

Let $r_n$ denote a reflection about a line through the centre which is at angle of $n \pi / {\bf 6}$ from the x-axis, for $n\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$.

The permutations are thus:
$$\begin{align}
R_0 & = ()
\\ R_1 & = (123456) 
\\ R_2 & = (135)(246)
\\ R_3 & = (14)(25)(36)
\\ R_4 & = (153)(264)
\\ R_5 & = (165432)
\\[1ex] r_0 & = (26)(35) & = H
\\ r_1 & = (12)(36)(45) & = D_3  
\\ r_2 & = (13)(46)     & = D_1
\\ r_3 & = (14)(23)(56) &  = V
\\ r_4 & = (15)(24)     & = D_2
\\ r_5 & = (16)(25)(34) & = D_4
\end{align}$$
**Tip:** When written in this order a nice pattern emerges.  Pick a vertex and look to where it maps to in each subsequent rotation or reflection.  Use this pattern to help check your work in exams and such.