# Prove $D_6 \cdot \text{stab}_{S6}(2) \leq S_6.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism, dihedral-groups

I wish to show $D_6 \cdot \text{stab}_{S6}(2) \leq S_6$, where $D_6$ is the dihedral group of order $12$ and $S_6$ is the symmetric group of order $6$.

- I have been able to provide the start of a rough, geometric argument as to why $D_6$ should be considered isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_6$: in labelling the vertices of a hexagon by $1, 2, ..., 6$, one can create a $1-1$ correspondence between the $12$ elements of $D_6$ and a collection $\mathcal{S}$ of $12$ distinct permutations in $S_6$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/884276/symmetric-group-of-a-hexagon-as-permutations)). In applying **Cayley's Theorem**, $D_6$ is guaranteed to be isomorphic to a *group* of permutations. In having created this $1-1$ correspondence, I suspect it *logically* (?) follows that $\mathcal{S} \subseteq S_6$ is the desired *group* of permutations, to which $D_6$ is isomorphic. Hence, we have $ D_6 \approx \mathcal{S} \leq S_6.$ (Is there any flaw in this argument)?
- Now, we have that $D_6 \leq S_6$ and $\text{stab}_{S6}(2) \leq S_6.$ To show $D_6 \cdot \text{stab}_{S6}(2) \leq S_6$, I believe I must show that $D_6 \cdot \text{stab}_{S6}(2) = \text{stab}_{S6}(2) \cdot D_6$. However, I am stuck at this step–– how would this proof proceed? Equivalently, I have thought of using the finite subgroup test, but again do not know how to prove the property of closure, i.e., if $\alpha, \beta \in D_6 \cdot \text{stab}_{S6}(2)$, so that $\alpha = \delta_1 \kappa_1$, $\beta = \delta_2 \kappa_2$, where $\delta_1, \delta_2 \in D_6$ and $\kappa_1, \kappa_2 \in \text{stab}_{S6}(2)$, then $ab = \delta_1 \kappa_1 \delta_2 \kappa_2 \in  D_6 \cdot \text{stab}_{S6}(2).$

Comment: What is $\operatorname{stab}_{S6}(2)$? Are those permutations that leave $2$ fixed?

Comment: Yes, $\text{stab}_{S6}(2)$ is the stabiliser of $2$ in $S_6$, defined as follows  $\text{stab}_{S6}(2) = \{g \in S_6: g(2) = 2\}.$

Comment: Thank you. Then it seems right to me to prove that $\operatorname{stab}_{S_6}(2)D_6=D_6\operatorname{stab}_{S_6}(2)=S_6$.

Comment: The result is true whatever numbering you choose for the vertices of the hexagon, but in principle it could depend this numbering, because if you you use a different numbering then you get a different subgroup $D_6$.

Comment: One way perhaps to show this is to prove that $\delta_1 \kappa_1 \delta_2 \kappa_2 = \delta_1 \delta_2 (\delta_2^{-1} \kappa_1 \delta_2)\kappa_2$, but this would require that $\text{stab}$ is a normal subgroup–– which is false?

Comment: @kabenyuk To be sure, $\text{stab}_{S6}(2) D_6 = S_6$ (not a subset thereof)?

Comment: What I meant was this. Since the subgroup index $\operatorname{stab}_{S_6}(2)$ in $S_6$ is $6$ and $D_6<S_6$ for each $i=1,\ldots,6$ contains permutation $\sigma$, such that $\sigma(2)=i$, it follows that $D_6\operatorname{stab}_{S_6}(2)$ contains the left cosets of $\operatorname{stab}_{S_6}(2)$ in $S_6$ (multiplication of permutations from right to left).